# cannot delete files and folders with long names in windows

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for deleting directories with path/names too long for normal delete](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete)

I have used FBackup to backup to my external hard drive and now I am trying to delete this backup from the external hard drive but it wont allow me.

There is at least 100Gb of data and I can delete the culprit files if I dig deep and then go an rename that folder to a shorter name but I don't want to have to do this for 100Gb of data.

Is there a utility I can use to sort this out with please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Managed to find the answer in another post, thanks!

rd /S \?\C:\VeryLongFolderName

http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/LongFilenames.asp