# Windows File Delete Deadlock

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for deleting directories with path/names too long for normal delete](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete)

I have annoying folder with long file name which i want to completely delete, bt i tried all my headaround but still didnt do any good , actually impossible to delete this files, deadlock i guess... see below for more information

```
C:\Windows.old\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\WinStore_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\Microsoft\Windows Store\Cache\0>del 0-Namespace-https???services.apps.microsoft.com?browse?6.2.9200-1?615?en-GB?c?AU?Na
0000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.dat
The filename or extension is too long.

C:\Windows.old\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\WinStore_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\Microsoft\Windows Store\Cache\0>ren 0-Namespace-https???services.apps.microsoft.com?browse?6.2.9200-1?615?en-GB?c?AU?Na
0000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.dat ddd.sss
The filename or extension is too long.

C:\Windows.old\Users\XXx\AppData\Local\Packages\WinStore_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\Microsoft\Windows Store\Cache\0>ren 0-Namespace-https???services.apps.microsoft.com?browse?6.2.9200-1?615?en-GB?c?AU?Na
0000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000?00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.dat ddd.ss
The filename or extension is too long.

C:\Windows.old\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Packages\WinStore_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\Microsoft\Windows Store\Cache\0>
```

Comment: why do you want to delete them? Those folders belong to the new "Windows Store Apps".

Comment: @magicandre1981, it's C:\Windows.old, which is evidently an old installation of Windows that user1179459 doesn't want.

Comment: @dangph good catch! I overlooked this. The topic starter should use disk cleanup to kill the complete Windows.old folder.