# In Windows 7, how do I get around the "The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder" error?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

## Background

I am working on analyzing a large base of source code provided to me as a 5GB .zip file.  I need to maintain the exact file structure when extracting, however, when I attempt to extract I get an error message saying:

`The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder.`

I understand that this is due to Windows' 260 character limit on file paths, but there is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982502/en-us) for this published by Microsoft.

I downloaded the hotfix, ran as an administrator, but then got another error:

`This update is not applicable to your computer.`

Well, according to the hotfix literature, it should be exactly applicable to my computer.

## My System

- Windows 7 Ultimate
- SP1
- x64

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't need the Hotfix (from 2010), as you probably already have an updated version of the files it fixes.  If you look at the hotfix article, it tells you which file(s) will be updated to which version by the hotfix.  It says it will update the 64-bit "wbengine.exe" to 6.1.7600.20690.  My Win 7 64-bit SP1 machine is fully up to date; I never applied that hotfix, and yet my wbengine.exe is at version 6.1.7601.17514, so the hotfix wouldn't apply to me either, as I have an even newer version of the file already.

Comment: Actually, once you click the blue hotfix button, it brings you to a screen that allows you to select x64 which I have done.  Thanks though.

Comment: Sounds like the file path is simply to long.  Try make the file path shorter to verify thats the problem.

Comment: @techie007--Ok, thanks, but even if that is the case, the original problem still persists.  Vista allowed for long file paths, so I can't imagine that Win 7 can't do it.

Comment: The path length includes the folder you are extracting it too as well.  So perhaps try extracting it to a folder with a short name, something like "C:\a"?

Comment: 7 allows the same path length Vista did.

Comment: @Ramhound--Yes, thanks, I have verified that is the problem.  The file path is indeed too long.  That is the problem I need to solve by means other than changing the file path (if possible).

Comment: @techie007--Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried that too.  Still too long.  So that makes for an interesting point--the source machine (from which the .zip was produced) didn't have the problem I am having which must mean that there is a fix or workaround, right?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you extract the `.zip` archive with a third party program, e.g. [7-Zip](http://7-zip.org/)?

Comment: @and31415, no, but the files (example someFile.cs) all have 0 bytes.  I am starting to suspect there may be an encryption problem also.

Comment: [How to delete directories with path/names too long for normal delete](http://superuser.com/q/78434/241386)

Answer (score 5):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Have you checked the version of `wbengine.exe` installed on your system? Maybe you already have a newer one, and thus the hotfix won't install.
2. As a temporary work around, you could use [Delimon Win32 Explorer](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Delimon-Win32-Explorer-V40-bc957ab4), which uses a different library that gets around the 260-character issue (it supports up to 32K characters) and seems to work in Win7. Make sure you check the "Known Issues" section.

Addition: When you're using Delimon Explorer, you can assign a different program to become the default program for an extension. For this question, right click any zip file, click on `Properties` and next to the `Opens with` section, you'll see a `Change...` button. Click it and select the program you would like to use to open/view the file.

Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried it but sadly, I can't extract from a .zip file within the Delimon program.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you using Explorer's built-in Zip extractor? Try 7-zip, or if you are comfortable with the command line, you could try Info-ZIP's unzip.exe. Not sure if 7-zip's works from the GUI, as I've found mention of having to use list files.

Comment: the good thing is it's an official workaround so no problem.