# Backing up files with path names longer than 260 characters

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, backup

I can save files with long path names (< 260 characters) onto the local hard drive of my PC that has Windows 10. My passport backup system will show the backed up file in the directory, but I will not be able to open it. If my passport backup is connected to the PC I have that has Windows 7, I will be able to open it.

Is here a way that I can open it when the external passport drive is connected to my PC that has Windows 10?

Comment: Sounds like you enabled the optional long path Windows 10 feature.  Windows 7 doesn’t have this features. I assume you want to view these files on Windows 7 machine not the Windows 10 machine as you indicated in your question

Comment: Strictly speaking, long path support has been there in WinNT for ~20 years, just limited to specially-written software up until Win10. I wonder what backup software OP is using.

Comment: Not sure if this might help:https://superuser.com/questions/705417/in-windows-7-how-do-i-get-around-the-the-file-names-would-be-too-long-for-th