# Any need nowadays to be concerned about the 260 character path limit for non-networked files?

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-transfer, path, compatibility

For non-networked files, is there any need to take care nowadays about not exceeding the 260 character path limit?

I am most interested in answers covering Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and 10, if possible.

The only thing I can think of is if a specific software application is old and does not support long paths.

Is there anything else to consider?

Comment: Only Windows 10 supports more a NTFS path that has more than 260 characters.  At this time there is no version of Windows that has a version of File Explorer that can navigate a path longer than 260 characters.  In order for an application to be able to navigate it must specifically be written to support it.  Please narrow down the focus of your question, as it is written, the question is extremely broad.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your comment. As you likely know, I have much respect for your knowledge and always appreciate your help.  You posted something similar in the following question, but it sounds like it was disputed: https://superuser.com/questions/1372658/backing-up-files-with-path-names-longer-than-260-characters.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't know.  To my knowledge NTFS long path support was a new feature in 2015 with Windows 10 1511.  I am not aware of any version of Windows that support navigating to a path with more than 260 characters with File Explorer.  [Yes;](https://superuser.com/questions/705417/in-windows-7-how-do-i-get-around-the-the-file-names-would-be-too-long-for-th?noredirect=1&lq=1), I suppose you could always get around the limit, but never using a native Windows library.

Comment: @Ramhound I certainly don't currently consider myself an expert on long path support either (hence this question!). FWIW, I don't use Microsoft's File Explorer in Windows at all. The only exception might be that in some applications it's possible that the Open/Save dialogs are technically created by File Explorer DLLs. I don't recall offhand.