# Delete folder, subfolder and files in long path

Tags: windows-7

I have tried solving this problem by googling and browsing superuser.com, but haven't found a viable solution yet. I'm running Windows 7 btw.

I somehow got Arduino to recursively create folders named "libraries" within the parent-folder called libraries. Somewhere down the path, there are also some library-files and now I can't delete the damn thing.
The path is so deep, that I can't enter it all the way down to the files.
Every time I try to delete the files I get an error saying either something like "path too long" or "Directory not empty".

I have tried deleting it through the cmd.exe using:

```
del /S /Q libraries\*
rmdir /S /Q libraries
```

I also tried robocopy, as some threads mentioned this as a solution.

```
robocopy ROBCOP libraries /s /mir
```

And finally I have tried using a tool called DelinvFile. This tool started to delete the folder, but after deleting ~6000 subfolders, it stopped with the error "Directory not empty".

Comment: Most likely you're seeing issues with this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed different types of software, including some recursive deletion tools. In all cases the software crashed.

I managed to delete the folder, by installing a version of Ubuntu on a USB-stick, booting it up in Ubuntu and deleting it through the terminal using the recursive (-r) parameter. It took between 5-10min for the computer to delete the folder (amazing, as it only contained folders and 300kb of data).

After reboot, Windows felt the need to repair windows. I got a notification saying Windows wasn't able to repair, but when I booted up again everyting was working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In this question: [How to delete directories with path/names too long for normal delete](https://superuser.com/questions/78434/tool-for-deleting-directories-with-path-names-too-long-for-normal-delete)

Someone suggested using 7zip as an alternative to explorer that has received quite a lot of votes. Perhaps that will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Far manager](http://www.farmanager.com/), it handles long paths better.

Overview from their website:

Far Manager is a program for managing files and archives in Windows operating systems. Far Manager works in text mode and provides a simple and intuitive interface for performing most of the necessary actions:

- viewing files and directories;
- editing, copying and renaming files;