# What's the reason for the "Could not find this item" error for an existing folder?

Tags: windows-10

from time to time it happens, that my Usenet download client (sabnzbd) downloads and extracts something which then results in a folder that's cannot be deleted or renamed. The result is a "Could not find this item" error. This is just the most common way how this error occurs on my machine, but it seems that there are several different ways that this error can come up. The folder is not in use nor blocked by any other application.

Googling for this error shows that this error isn't too uncommon and there are several solutions to get rid of the broken folder. Either by deleting it in the command prompt via the shortname or by using something like the 7zip explorer in which you can delete it for some reason.

What I never found is the reason why this happens. Now I am looking for a technical explanation how this can even happen. I am not looking for workarounds on how to delete such a defective folder.

Comment: It doesn't appear you're actually asking for help solving a problem. It seems you've already solve it, and are instead asking us to guess why a particular error occurs. We cannot answer that question.

Comment: @music2myear I don't want you to guess, I am looking for someone who actually knows the technical reason why that specific error occurs. I also don't have a solution, I have a workaround how to manually remove such a folder.

Comment: Then you need to a) edit this question to remove the request for opinion and add the request for a solution, and b) send your question about why it is happening to the developer's forum. We didn't write this utility here and cannot say why it is giving you this error.

Comment: a) I am not looking for opinions, I am looking for a technical explanation.
b) The error isn't specific to that application, it's just one way how that error can occur.

Comment: Most likely the path is too long to be handled with older Windows APIs, and that's what Explorer uses. [Clickety click](https://superuser.com/q/78434/194694).