# Recursively delete files of a certain extension - File name is too long (Win Server 2012)

Tags: filenames, recursive

A while back, I created .hash files for all files in a given folder structure for verification purposes.  I no longer need them and they are minor annoyance/cause for alarm.  I am trying to recursively `del` them using `del /S *.hash` but I am running into the "filename is too long" error.  There are tons of these files, so I cannot simply rename them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: there are some great ideas on the linked thread in Dario's answer. I personally like to use the `subst` command to link the directory containing the file to `b:\\` so that the path is compressed to 3 characters and the rest can be used for filename. other than that, using ~ name abbreviation as described in the linked question works pretty well as long as your filename is unique in its first 6 chars.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this questions has been asked once or twice before.  I had a quick search and found this :
[How to delete a file in Windows with a too long filename?](https://superuser.com/questions/45697/how-to-delete-a-file-in-windows-with-a-too-long-filename?rq=1)

Have a look and see if this assists you, if not, let me / us know and will see what else can be done....

The simplest and best answer seems to be this one from @hectorpal : [Using Robocopy](https://superuser.com/a/1048242/652596)

Comment: Thanks, I've read that thread and I don't know if I can apply any of the suggestions to this application....

I may be able to use the shortened name solution by printing to a text file and then modifying that text file to be a series of commands...

Comment: Ah - this came through just as I edited the answer - take a look at http://superuser.com/a/1048242/652596 as @hectorpal describes using robocopy

Comment: I can't wrap my head around how to do that just to .hash files though.  These are all suggestions for removing entire folders, which I don't want to do, the data is very important.

Comment: Yep - sorry got that after re-reading your post.  OK ... Would I be correct in thinking that they are deep within a sub-folder structure? i.e. C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\longfilename.hash and may well appear in all of the sub-folders, so you need to go through each sub-folder and delete only the .hash files ... do I understand correctly?