# How to delete thousands of files that have names that are too long?

Tags: windows-8, file-management

I'm using Windows 8.1 and have several backups that I want to delete, but the file names are too long for thousands of files.  How can I delete them?

All of the solutions I've seen require that I shorten the names of the files or directories which would be very tedious for this number of files.

Comment: You don't need to rename all of the file names. You start by renaming the root directories in the tree to single-character names. Most of the time, you'll quickly get all of the file's names underneath these base folders short enough to delete them all.

Comment: Another question with good answers is this: https://superuser.com/questions/45697/how-to-delete-a-file-in-windows-with-a-too-long-filename/467814#467814

Comment: Robocopy (the third highest solution) worked.  The other top two did not. Manually renaming hundreds of file folders is not what I wanted to do, and 7-Zip File Manager didn't work.